# How do I pass angular services into Tabulator JS?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, tabulator

I am attempting to set a rowClick() function on a Tabulator table.
The rowClick() will pass the row Data into a service.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FuzeUser } from 'src/app/models/fuze-user';
import { UserEditService } from 'src/app/services/user-edit.service';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';
import Tabulator from 'tabulator-tables';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-table',
  templateUrl: './user-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-table.component.scss']
})
export class UserTableComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  tab = document.createElement('div');
  public tableName: string = 'fuze-user-table';
  private columns: any[] = [];
  private rows: any[] = [];
  table: Tabulator;
  public drawn: boolean = false;
  

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private userEditService: UserEditService) {
  }



  private drawTable(): void {
    this.table = new Tabulator(this.tab, {
      layout: "fitDataStretch",
      movableColumns: true,
      maxHeight:"485px",
      pagination: "local",
      paginationSize: 25,
      paginationSizeSelector: [25, 50, 100],
      selectable: true,
      selectableRangeMode: "click",
      data: this.rows,
      columns: this.columns,
      rowClick:function(e, id, data, row){
        this.userEditService.setUser(data);
      }
    });
    document.getElementById(`${this.tableName}`).appendChild(this.tab);
  }
}
```

I think that the service cannot be found because the scope of "this" within the rowClick() function only exists within the Tabulator object.

I have also attempted to create a function, that calls this.userEditService.setUser, within my component class, and then passed that method to tabulator. This also failed because the method passed cannot find anything within the scope of the service.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FuzeUser } from 'src/app/models/fuze-user';
import { UserEditService } from 'src/app/services/user-edit.service';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';
import Tabulator from 'tabulator-tables';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-table',
  templateUrl: './user-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-table.component.scss']
})
export class UserTableComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  tab = document.createElement('div');
  public tableName: string = 'fuze-user-table';
  private columns: any[] = [];
  private rows: any[] = [];
  table: Tabulator;
  public drawn: boolean = false;
  

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private userEditService: UserEditService) {
  }

  private setUser(data: FuzeUser){
    this.userEditService.setUser(data)
  }

  private drawTable(callback: (user: any) => void): void {
    this.table = new Tabulator(this.tab, {
      layout: "fitDataStretch",
      movableColumns: true,
      maxHeight:"485px",
      pagination: "local",
      paginationSize: 25,
      paginationSizeSelector: [25, 50, 100],
      selectable: true,
      selectableRangeMode: "click",
      data: this.rows,
      columns: this.columns,
      rowClick:function(e, id, data, row){
        callback(data);
      }
    });
    document.getElementById(`${this.tableName}`).appendChild(this.tab);
  }
}
```

How do I go about getting access to my service from within the tabulator object?

Answer (score 0):

Save a reference to the function and use it in the Tabulator contructor

```
const callback = this.userEditService.setUser;

this.table = new Tabulator(this.tab, {
  layout: "fitDataStretch",
  ...
  rowClick:function(e, id, data, row){
    callback(data);
  }
});
```

EDIT
oh i saw u tried it. So setUser() method is using something from userEditSerivce?

EDIT2
arrow function should do the trick

```
const callback = this.userEditService.setUser;

this.table = new Tabulator(this.tab, {
  layout: "fitDataStretch",
    ...
    rowClick: (e, id, data, row) => {
      callback(data);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Regarding your comment: Correct. The ```setUser(user)``` method will push the user value into a ```BehaviorSubject<User>``` by calling ```this.$user.next(user)```